# Why does xgboost cross validation perform so well while train/predict performs so poorly?

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm working with xgboost, and I'm trying to train a model. Here's some of my code:

```
def trainModel(training_data_filepath):

    training_data = loadDataFromFile(training_data_filepath)

    algorithm_parameters = {'max_depth': 2, 'eta': 1, 'silent': 1, 'objective': 'binary:logistic'}
    num_rounds = 1

    print xgb.cv(algorithm_parameters, training_data, num_rounds, nfold=2, metrics={'error'}, seed=0)
    return xgb.train(algorithm_parameters, training_data)
```

Cross validation prints out:

```
test-error-mean  test-error-std  train-error-mean  train-error-std
       0.020742               0          0.019866         0.000292
```

Which to me reads two percent test error which is pretty good. But with the trained model that's returned I also run a test of my own, on a holdout set which is drawn from the training set:

```
def testModel(classifier, test_data_filepath):

    test_data = loadDataFromFile(test_data_filepath)
    predictions = classifier.predict(test_data)
    labels = test_data.get_label()

    test_error = sum([1 for i in range(len(predictions)) if int(predictions[i]>0.5) != labels[i]]) / float(len(predictions))
    print 'Classifier test error: ' + `test_error`
```

Which comes out to

```
Classifier test error: 0.2786214953271028
```

Which is 27% which is much worse. Why did this happen? How can a model trained on all of the training data fail on the holdout set when cross validation on the training set performs so well? I have to imagine there's something wrong with my logic, but I don't see anything. That or the xgboost implementation of CV does something I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was being a goof. 
I was creating the training and hold out sets separately, so they had different indices for different tokens, meaning it's a miracle it was doing so much better than random chance. I think that's what confused me -- it did so much better than 50% accuracy even with totally different indexing of features.